# How to run a https secured app in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to run my app inside kubernetes cluster on https and expose it outside the cluster also over https. I created the `pod` and exposed the port `443`. After that I created a `ClusterIP` service which connects to the pod on port `443` and expose also port `443`. Lastly, I created an `ingress` which connects to the service on port `443`. I deployed all of these resources using helm chart on GKE. I use `NGINX Ingress` controller. You can find the chart [here](https://github.com/b-rohit/https-app/tree/master/chart).

When I access the app internally in the cluster over https it works.

```
curl https://my-nginx.https-app-64-production --cacert /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I access it using external url then I get below error.

```
curl https://staging.vs-creator.iotcrawler.eu/
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. I suspect it is to do with ingress controller configuration. Please help me on this.

Comment: which ingress controller your are using...is it nginx?

Comment: yes, nginx-ingress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below annotation in ingress resourece

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)

> Using backend-protocol annotations is possible to indicate how NGINX
> should communicate with the backend service. (Replaces secure-backends
> in older versions) Valid Values: HTTP, HTTPS, GRPC, GRPCS, AJP and
> FCGI

By default NGINX uses `HTTP` while forwarding the request to backend pod which leads to `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port` because the backend pod is expecting `HTTPS` request.